# How to enable both http and https tunnels in ngrok?

Tags: ngrok

The ngrok help doc says: ***line 3: Only HTTPS tunnels by default - ngrok agent HTTP tunnels by default will only open a single HTTPS endpoint for your upstream service instead of both an HTTP and HTTPS endpoint. To enable both, you will need to add --scheme http --scheme https to your ngrok agent command or configuration file.***

I tried to update the configuration file, but no success. I got "ERROR:    line 3: field schemes not found in type config.v2yamlConfig"

```
version: "2"
authtoken: faswETNh3FAW8DSmVuHrOH18s_6pK7iuqkQP5
schemes: http,https
```

I also tried the following. I got "ERROR:    line 3: field scheme not found in type config.v2yamlConfig"

```
version: "2"
authtoken: faswETNh3FAW8DSmVuHrOH18s_6pK7iuqkQP5
scheme: http,https
```

Comment: DId you try this:
`scheme: http scheme: https`

Comment: Yes, I tried, and I was getting the  error:  YAML parsing error: yaml: line 3: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ngrok version 3.0.0 has renamed `bind_tls` to `schemes` [ngrok changelog](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/changelog):

[changelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCs4o.png)

Try this:

```
version: 2
authtoken: <TOKEN>
tunnels:
  rails:
    proto: http
    addr: 5000
    schemes: [https, http]
  react:
    proto: http
    addr: 8080
    schemes: [https, http]
```